# How to copy a file from one directory to another directory by creating the folder if that folder does not exist

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, directory, copy

I have some problem with copying the file from one directory to another directory by creating the folder if that folder does not exist in the destination directory.

Example:

- Source path: `C:\temp\test\1.txt`
- Destination path: `C:\Data\`

If `C:\Data\` doesn't contain "temp" or "test" folder, it should create the folder before coping `1.txt`.

Copied to `C:\Data\temp\test\1.txt`

Below is my code. But it doesn't work..

```
Private Sub btnBackup_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBackup.Click
          Dim sourcepath As String = "C:\temp\test\1.txt"
    Dim DestPath As String = "C:\Data\"
    CopyDirectory(sourcepath, DestPath)
End Sub

Private Shared Sub CopyDirectory(sourcePath As String, destPath As String)
    If Not Directory.Exists(destPath) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destPath)
    End If

    For Each file__1 As String In Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath)
        Dim dest As String = Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(file__1))
        File.Copy(file__1, dest)
    Next

    For Each folder As String In Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath)
        Dim dest As String = Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(folder))
        CopyDirectory(folder, dest)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Any errors? and are you using XP or Windows 7

Comment: Phrases like "it doesn't work" should be blocked by SO when submitting a question ;)

Answer (score 10):

The following is not a directory.

```
Dim sourcepath As String = "C:\temp\test\1.txt"
```

Because you are using it as a directory in `Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath)`.

Apart from that, I recommend to elaborate your questions more the next time. The code raises meaningful exceptions like `DirectoryNotFoundException` with the appropriate path as message or (if the file exists) an `IOException` with message *"The directory name is invalid"*. You should have added that to the question.

So the solution simply is to remove the `1.txt` from the directory-name:

```
Dim sourcepath As String = "C:\temp\test\"
```

If you need to copy only one file, use [CopyTo method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.copyto.aspx):

```
Dim sourcepath As String = "C:\temp\test\"
Dim DestPath As String = "C:\temp\Data\"
If Not Directory.Exists(DestPath) Then
    Directory.CreateDirectory(DestPath)
End If
Dim file = New FileInfo("C:\temp\test\1.txt")
file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(DestPath, file.Name), True)
```

Comment: I have a lot of text file but I want to copy 1.txt file only.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim strMasterResourceDirectory As String
    Dim strDirectory As String

    strDirectory = "C:\TestDestination"
    strMasterResourceDirectory = "TestResource"

   If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(strDirectory) = False Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(strDirectory)
    End If

    ' Loop through each file in the directory
    For Each file As IO.FileInfo In New IO.DirectoryInfo(strDirectory).GetFiles

        If file.Name <> "Thumbs.db" Then

            System.IO.File.Delete(strDirectory & "\" & file.Name)

        End If
    Next

    ' Loop through each file in the directory
    For Each file As IO.FileInfo In New IO.DirectoryInfo(strMasterResourceDirectory).GetFiles

        If file.Name <> "Thumbs.db" Then

            ' copy resource to users local directory

            file.CopyTo(strDirectory & "\" & file.Name)

        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider adding a little explanation to your code. Thank you!